# How to select with Linq to Entity from one table with two different variables?

Tags: linq-to-entities

I have a table where I have items under two different types as you can see below: 
How can I select from this table with Linq to Entity to get the result with two variables?

```
where ItemType = Type1 and ItemType == Type2
.... select new {typeOne == "", typeTwo == ""};

ID ItemName     ItemType

1 ItemOne       Type1
2 ItemTwo       Type1
3 ItemThree     Type1
4 ItemFour      Type1
5 ItemTFive     Type2
6 ItemSix       Type2
7 ItemSeven     Type2
8 ItemEight     Type2
```

Comment: Don't really understand your question. Is this two columns in one table? If so, you just select and it will contain itemname and type

Comment: yes one table, can you please show me an example

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming (based on your comments) that you want to find the items where the ItemType matches either one column or another, then map the correct column *name* to ItemType in the output.  I'll show it using the fluent-style, extension methods.

```
 var query = db.Items
               .Where( i => i.Type1 == ItemType || i.Type2 == ItemType )
               .Select( i => new
                {
                    ID = i.ID, 
                    ItemName = i.ItemName,
                    ItemType = ItemType == i.Type1 ? "Type1" : "Type2"
                });
```

If I've misunderstood your intentions, please leave a comment and clarify.

Comment: I would like to select type1 and type2 at the same time just using 2 variable